# how to unzip downloaded files

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to restore programs in Ubuntu that I have on my unstable Win-7 partition.  I've downloaded the zip file for one of those and when I click on it an Archive Manager opens that says "An error occurred while loading the archive."   What the heck does that mean and how do I fix it?
Thanks,
HB

Comment: In all probability, that would mean the zip file is corrupted or partially downloaded.

Comment: I figured out how to unzip the file.   I created a new directory and moved the zip file to it.  Then went to a terminal window and accessed that directory and gave the unzip command.

Comment: My problem now is how to be able to run that program.   I get the same error message as before when I click on the executable program.

Answer (score 3):

Install `7zip` and `unzip` by executing the following command on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install 7zip unzip
```

and then use the terminal to unzip the file by executing the following in the terminal:

```
unzip filename -d directory
```